# How does this video load so quickly?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, streaming

In a pretty impressive display of web design, the video link [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview) begins playing immediately, with audio. How does it accomplish this?

Comment: As always, I've mis-stepped within the guidelines of the overflow etiquette. Can anyone be so kind as to explain the errors of my ways? I'm seriously trying to engage here, and I have no idea why this is outside of the applicable question case.

Comment: read http://WhatHaveYouTried.com, it should be help you post better questions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They download the first few seconds of video on the first page, before you actually click "watch the video". Then they download the rest only if you start the video.

Try looking at it with a tool like developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox. When I load the first page, I see c46d7659-2578-42b8-a671-e59ef633eae7_16.mp4 (2.1 MB) downloaded with HTTP code 206 -- Partial Content. Later if you play the video, it's this file that grows.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an autoplay attribute with the new  element in html 5:

```
    <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp